# Is there any corner case when malloc/calloc/realloc will fail?

Tags: c

I have heard that it's good practice to check if malloc/realloc/calloc operation was successful.
Wondering what are the cases/corner cases where it will fail, and how common these cases could be.

Comment: Running out of memory would be the obvious one.

Comment: It is not good practice to check whether memory allocation functions were successful. It is good practice to check for *all possible error conditions*.